# Tensorflow C api "Error: Container localhost does not exist."

Tags: c, tensorflow

While running a keras model saved as a .pb file in C using tensorflow c_api.h, I run into this error.

```
Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable value_dense_2/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/value_dense_2/bias) [[{{node nnue_model/value_dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp}}]] [[StatefulPartitionedCall/_35]]
```

The **solution for it in python** can be found [here](https://github.com/cleverhans-lab/cleverhans/issues/1117) and in code it looks something like this:

```
session = keras.backend.get_session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(init)`
```

So I would like to know how to implement this solution in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: I used only the **saved_model.pb** file but the `model.save()` function creates two additional folders named **assets** and **variables** which I didn't see at the start. So to solve the error I just had to copy those 2 folders along with the saved_model.pb file.

Comment: Thank you. I made similar mistake :-) I copied only `saved_model.pb` file and was thinking that it was enough so struggled many hours to figure out the problem. Finally fixed it :-)